# Apple AR Kit feature points for entire session

Tags: ios, swift, feature-extraction, arkit

I understand how to extract feature points for a single ARFrame (ARFrame.rawFeaturePoints). Is there anyway to extract all feature points that have been detected in the session? Is this something I have to aggregate myself? If so, how should I handle point matching?

Comment: Welcome to stack overflow. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour).

Answer (score 0):

find the ways to capture the feature points.

1. You can implement the **ARSCNViewDelegate**, you will get a callback whenever AR finds plane..here you can capture all the feature points.

   `func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, didAdd node: SCNNode, for anchor: ARAnchor) {
           if let planeAnchor = anchor as? ARPlaneAnchor {
               let cloudPoints = sceneView.session.currentFrame?.rawFeaturePoints
           }
       }`

2.You can implement the **SCNSceneRendererDelegate**, implement the 
`func renderer(_ renderer: SCNSceneRenderer, updateAtTime time: TimeInterval) { }`.